# Trouble looping through function in R

Tags: r, loops, census

I am trying to loop through a function in R. I want to loop through 62 stored values but the loop only seems to run and save for the last output. I am new to loops and think this may be an easy fix

my stored vales are:

```
    state_county
state:36+county:015
state:36+county:063
state:36+county:007
state:36+county:081
state:36+county:055
```

my code is:

```
    for (i in state_county)
{
  test <-  getCensus(name = "acs/acs5",
               vintage = 2016, 
               vars = c("NAME", "B19013_001E"), 
               region = "Block Group:*", 
               regionin = i)
}
```

'regionin' must be in format: state:""+county:""

The end result will only return a data frame for state:36+county:055 (the last value in my stored value set

Comment: Are you familiar with the `tidycensus` package? If not, you may find it useful. Personally, I'd pull the full file and then filter the data from a look up table. https://cran.r-project.org/web/packages/tidycensus/index.html

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It's a bit difficult to give a full answer when reproducible data is not present.
However, what happens is that you keep saving your new calculation over and over under the same variable.

I created a `list` variable `results` which will save the outputs of each iteration
.
Given that `state_county` is some kind of a list or vector, I used `length` to find out how long it is. Next, I iterate over each item starting with one and saving the `test` variable inside `results`.

```
results <- list()
for (i in 1:length(state_county)))
{
  test <-  getCensus(name = "acs/acs5",
                     vintage = 2016, 
                     vars = c("NAME", "B19013_001E"), 
                     region = "Block Group:*", 
                     regionin = state_county[[i]])
  
  results[[i]] <- test
}
```

Comment: Thank you! this is exactly what I was looking for

Comment: Glad I could help! :)